# NetAddresses always null in Win32_NetworkAdapter query

Tags: c#, networking, wmi

I am trying to get the active network adapter's IP address, so that I avoid virtual and other VPN adapters that are not connected at present.

On my current laptop the following code returns 3 IP V4 addresses, and I don't know how to get the "real", in use IP address from that list.

```
        IPAddress[] ipV4Addresses = Array.FindAll(
            Dns.GetHostEntry(String.Empty).AddressList,
            a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Looking at MSDN doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I thought maybe I was on the right track.  Has anyone obtained the list of IP addresses per adapter successfully?  If so, please share your wisdom.  Thanks!

This is all prototype at this point. I have this code (thanks to SO!), and the string[] netAddresses is always null, even with the computer connected to a network and with a functioning IP address.

```
        string wmiQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionId != NULL";
        ManagementObjectSearcher moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection moCollection = moSearch.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", mo["Name"], mo["NetConnectionStatus"]);
            string[] netAddresses = (string[])mo["NetworkAddresses"];
            if (netAddresses != null)
            {
                foreach (string netAddress in netAddresses)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tnet addresses:");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}", netAddress);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Define "real". Any or all of the IPv4 addresses could be in use at once. What if your PC has two or more "real" NICs?

Comment: @Gaz, sorry for the non-technical term "real".  What I mean is the NIC that is currently plugged in, and used for communicating with the internet via a browser.  I know more than one NIC may be plugged in at a time, but in our user base that will be extremely rare if at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from MS docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

NetworkAddresses

Data type: string array
Access type: Read-only

Array of network addresses for an adapter. This property is inherited from CIM_NetworkAdapter.

This property has not been implemented yet. It returns a NULL value by default.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "real" IP address. Each packet you send is routed to its destination based on the metric of the adapter and the available routing paths. You can guess which IP is primarily being used for internet traffic by doing the following:

1. Order your adapters by metric, lowest first.
2. Prioritise WAN IPs, then 192.168.x.x, then 10.x.x.x, and totally ignore loopback addresses.

This will give you a guess as to the "preferred" address, though it's hardly definitive.

Answer (score 1):

Look at WIn32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration, by using the InterfaceIndex from Win32_NetworkAdapter you should be able to get the configuration you need with the ipaddresses assigned to that nic.